# how can I draw custom button with background Image "info" in the UINavigationBar

Tags: image, button, uinavigationbar

I have to implement the custom button having image "info", the link of the image is below. I have to implement this button in the navigation bar in the right side of the navigation bar. I had tried with UIBarButtonItem  but can't change the background of the button. Is there any why to add this type of image in the navigaiton bar?

The link for the image "info".

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_3RVFhWaR5zA/SjVfKOB5UoI/AAAAAAAABAI/heQRpNW0eX8/s400/information_icon.jpg